# Encryption of message in client and server communication

Tags: php, encryption, https, client-server

How to encrypt the text travelling between client and server in the following code. I am aware that `https` will encrypt the tunnel but I want to know how to encrypt the text.

if I use any algorithm of encrytion at the script, being server side script, the encryption will occur at the server end and not before the text starts flowing from the client to the server.

```
<HTML>
  <form method="POST" action="TESTING.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    NAME:  <input type="text" name="username">
    PASSWORD:  <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Save and Proceed">
  </form>
</html>

<?php 

  if(isset($_POST['username']))
  { 
    echo"db operation"; 
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little sense in applying two encryption layers on top of each other. If you use https that should be a) secure and b) sufficient, except for *very* special cases.

Apart from that: there is no reliable way to implement a secure encryption between a web client and server on application level. The problem simply is that all knowledge required to encrypt such on the client side that the server will be able to decrypt the data again would make the effort fruitless. *Except* when using asymetric, key based encryption as ssl does, but then again that *is* what is done for the https protocol.

Oh, and a side note: the md5 sum algorithm you mention in your code example is *not* encryption, it is hashing. Very basic hashing offering a very low level of security, by the way. That is something completely different. you could certainly hash a password on the client side (by means of using javascript, not php), but that makes no sense at the end.

What you should do in typical situations is this (best practice): use https for the transport layer (force it, refuse http usage). Then, on the server side apply a *good* and "salted" hashing algorithm on the password and save that hash in a database. Upon authentication requests against those credentials you then compare hashes of the password (one hash fro the database, on from the password used during the authentication). That way the password itself is not at all stored on the server side.

Have fun!

Comment: firstly thank you for explaining it. The reason why  intend to do so is because I made a small authentication scheme for user authentication in php and i want the data to be encrypted in my scheme too so that I use it with http or https its secure always. I want to know how to encrypt the data at the client site itself because any encryption in php script will be a server side processing which does not solve the purpose. Thank you again

Comment: Sure, I understood that from your question. But as explained above: such encryption is insecure per definition. Given that, it is useless. Even worth: it pretends a false sense of security where none really exists. It could be easily attacked, since all required information _must_ be present in the client, in every client. So a potential attacker has all the time in the world to craft his attack. You should trust in 40 years of experience that bright computer scientists all around the world gathered in that field :-)